# Visual Studio Code mistakenly convert all tab keypress to literal "tab"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suddenly my code convert any tab keypress to literal "tab" as shown in below code snippet:

```
def getLogger(name):

daiquiri.setup(
    level=app.config.get('LOG_LEVEL', logging.INFO),
    outputs=(<tab><tab><tab><tab><tab>
        daiquiri.output.File(directory="log"),
    ))

return daiquiri.getLogger(name)
```

You can see there are few *tab* in the code. Whenever I type tab key it become tab text.

Answer (score 0):

Just come back to answer the question.

The actually cause still not clear, but it's sure that it happens only after I install and enable Git Pack extension.

The issue is gone once I disable the extension and reload Code.

By the way I also have my vim extension enabled which may conflict with Git Pack extension.